# Interfaces and Constructors in C#

Tags: c#, interface, compiler-errors

Ok I am sure something like this has come up before but I can't find anything on it. Seems simple and am sure the answer is obvious. here is my problem

I have a Interface called ICommand:

```
public interface ICommand
{
    void Do();
    void Undo();
}
```

Ok so now I have my class that uses the interface:

```
class SquareCommand : ICommand
{
    public SquareCommand(Bitmap abitmap, Color aColor, int x, int y)
    {

    }

    public void Do()
    {
    }
    public void Undo()
    {
    }
}

}
```

The error I getting is "Member names cannot be the same as their enclosing class" but the SquareCommand(...) is a Constructor not a member. I have looked for the obvious ones e.g. putting void in front(Constructors don't return anything) but I still can't seem to get this to compile when I think it should.

Comment: The shown code is correct. There must be something not shown here interferring

Comment: is this the complete code? if not, provide complete one. This compiles perfect.

Comment: what fields are in SquareCommand? What line does it say the error is on

Answer (score 0):

As others said in comments, the above code is OK, so you probalby pasted wrong part of the code :)

To speed up things, one of the most common issue with **contructors** that result in such error is when you accidentally mis-type constructor as a **method**, i.e.:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(int x) { .... }
    public void Foo(int x, int y) { .... }
}
```

Note that the second "constructor" has a return type specified: void. It is invalid for a constructor, so compiler threats it instead as a normal method, and then the **name** of that method collides with typename/constructorname and hence such error is raised.

Be sure to carefully check ALL constructors. If any has a returntype specified, remove it.

Other thing is when you copy/paste code between classes, or when you rename a class and fail to notice that there's a method of such name, i.e.:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Bar(int x) { ... }
}
```

If you force renaming the "Foo" into "Bar", then you'll get the error since the resulting code

```
public class Bar
{
    public void Bar(int x) { ... }
}
```

is invalid exactly due to the same problems as mentioned above. You'll have to decide: either class XOR the method can have such name. Rename the class, or rename the method to some other name.

Comment: Ok think I have got it sorted now. Thanks for all the assistance. The problem as someone has said was not with that code but with an enum I had which was called Color(hence the error) obviously it can't e called the same as a c# type i will have to change the name of that to something else. Its compiling fine now. Thanks to whoever pointed out I had missed the public before the class definition although not an error per say its obviously meant to be a public class not a internal one(which i think is what the absent of a public or private will default to). Thanks again all.